# one database for a consumer/seller website or two?

Tags: facebook

OK so I'm making a members only site. I want it set up so that every one has to log in to the site to access any features.

Thing is I need 2 types of accounts 1 for consumers (people wanting to buy the services) and a 2nd level account for users to have extra site feature to be able to sell the service and post ads and such.

As of now I have it set up in the data base where a user registers at my site it will send a verification email to there email and when the user clicks the activation link it simply changes the database *"activation"* from a 0 to a 1 witch gives that user access to the site.

So my question is can I just set the *"active"* in my database to go to a higher number such as 2 so that I can have *"active"* 1 as consumers and *"active"* 2 for sellers?

Or do I need to make a separate database for "consumer" and another database for the *"seller"*

thanks in advance.

Comment: No one has an answer?

Comment: Please do not post [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025397/do-i-use-one-database-or-two). Sometimes it takes a couple of hours before someone who can answer appropriately sees your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep both type of users in the same table, you can create a new row in the users table, let's call it "type", and in the register form you can put a select field with 2 options: 1 buyer, 2 seller, from which the user will choose, and which will update the "type" row, from your table.

Comment: Or you can call the new row "seller", which value is 0 or NULL by default, and you can put a checkbox in your signup form, and when it is checked, the "seller" is updated to 1. Good Luck!

Comment: AHHH, thank you very much for the helpful information.

Comment: you can also put 0 for inactive, 1 for buyer, and 2 for seller, but what if someone is both a buyer and a seller? In this case we need the new row I was talking about above. Best wishes!