# do I use one database or two?

Tags: android

OK so I'm making a members only site. I want it set up so that every one has to log in to the site to access any features.

Thing is I need 2 types of accounts 1 for consumers (people to buy the services thats in the ads.) and a 2nd level account for users to have extra site feature to be able to describe there business and post ads contact information, location, and such.

As of now I have it set up in the data base where a user registers at my site it will send a verification email to there email and when the user clicks the activation link it simply changes the database "activation" from a 0 to a 1 witch gives that user access to the site.

So my question is can I just set the "active" in my database to go to a higher number such as 2 so that I can have "active" 1 as consumers and "active" 2 for sellers?

Or do I need to make a separate database for "consumer" and another database for the "seller"

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is account information you wish to separate, I can think of no reason why this approach should not be valid. Think of the "active" property as an actual *status* where "0" means inactive, "1" means consumer, "2" means seller etc.
You could even put plain strings in there, like "INACTIVE", "CONSUMER", "SELLER", much like an enumeration type. It is all up to your implementation.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. I'm trying to create this website and though its some what tough I'm managing it slowly thanks to the good people here like you. I have a (what I believe) to be a fantastic idea for a website and just trying to get it built and tempt business waters ;)

Comment: If this answer helped you resolve the issue, you might want to accept it.